# cucumber error when include flat-ui css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I am running cucumber test suites for my rails project. everything is going well until I included a flat-ui css file today.

So, in my application.css, when I have the following libraries loaded

```
*= require bootstrap-3.1.1.min
*= require flat-ui-1.2.5
*= require lesshat-prefixed
*= require base
*= require_self
```

and run cucumber at project root, it reports the following error:

```
Invalid CSS after "...: scale(1.001, ": expected function argument, was ");"
```

Then if I remove the inclusion of flat-ui-1.2.5

```
*= require bootstrap-3.1.1.min
* require flat-ui-1.2.5 # remove this from require
*= require lesshat-prefixed
*= require base
*= require_self
```

then everything works fine.

#### So, is it because flat-ui have some error for compilation or have conflict with cucumber?

### Update

If I precompile the assets with rake assets:precompile, the the cucumber scenario test is executed successfully.

Comment: I have tried your solution by including flatui source file, but no luck.

The [error log](https://gist.github.com/fuyi/10959426) show something related to sass parser. any clue?

Answer (score 0):

In caret.less add a second paramater to the mixin call:

```
.scale(1.001, 1.001);
```

Comment: where is the caret.less file? is it in flat-ui source? I am using the minified version

Comment: I am not sure where it is in your version. I thought you are using the less files because those have this compilation issue. Try to search for .scale in your project.

Comment: I have tried your solution by including flatui source file, but no luck.

The [error log](https://gist.github.com/fuyi/10959426) show something related to sass parser. any clue?

Comment: The error is caused by an invalid call to this mixin: https://github.com/designmodo/Flat-UI/blob/master/less/mixins.less#L155 so what you should do is to search for that call and add a second parameter. A quick search gave me that caret.less file but there might be another occurences too.